# Kmeans clustering of nodes (data in the form of R dataframe : source, destination and distance) into equal size clusters

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a R dataframe containing the source node, the destination node and the distance between them. Here's a part of the dataframe :

[image: source, destination, distance]

I would like to cluster the nodes into groups of fixed size (say 8).
How do I implement this in R ?

EDIT 1 : As pointed out, kmeans is not applicable here. There is another clustering algorithm that might work [k-medoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids) / [pam](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/cluster/html/pam.html)

Here are some other links that might be interesting :

1) [Link1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12495/k-means-implementation-with-custom-distance-matrix-in-input)

2) [Link2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2717/clustering-with-a-distance-matrix)

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide more information including methods you have tried as well as a dataset the is in text format rather than an image. See the following on producing a [minimum example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Kmeans minimizes the distance from the kmeans centers and the individual data items.  The process is iterative with the location of the kmeans centers.  Kmeans may not the best method to cluster in this application since the data provided above looks to a directed graph and not a set of coordinates.

Comment: As Dave2e says, this looks like a directed graph. Have you looked into something like Gephi, which can apply clustering on top of this?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Don't understand the downvote.
I wanted to know if kmeans could be modified to get the job done, hence haven't tried anything apart from plotting a graph using igraph. So apparently not possible. Don't know Gephi or if it can do something that igraph cannot. Will give it a try.
Otherwise as @Anony-Mousse suggested, could anyone suggest a clustering algorithm that gives equal size clusters for this kind of dataset?

Answer (score 1):

K-means *can* only be used on **coordinates**.

It's computing *means*. You can only compute the mean on coordinates. You need to choose a different algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Could you please suggest an algorithm that gives equal sized clusters for this dataset ?

Comment: k-means also does not give equal sized clusters... you need to be clear on what you consider to be a good result before you can choose an algorithm. You can of course do hierarchical clustering or PAM. But whether they are good depends on your problem.